# Create multiple PDF files with PFDF?

Tags: python, pdf, for-loop, fpdf

This is the basic structure for the code I'm currently using to create one PDF file for each row in my CSV file. So if there are 10 rows, I am expecting an output of 10 PDFs. What I'm getting instead is one PDF with all the rows, which creates one large file.

```
with open('new1.csv', 'r', newline='') as x:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(x, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for x in data_reader:
        record = x['Test ID']
        record_str = 'Test ID: ' + record
        name = x['Name']
        name_1 = 'Name: ' + name
        pdf.cell(effective_page_width / 5.0, 0.0, record_str)
        pdf.cell(effective_page_width / 5.0, 0.0, name_1)

        More variables like the ones above

        pdf.output('Test.pdf', 'F')
```

Therefore, my questions are:
1) How do I print multiple PDFs?
2) How do I make each PDF have a unique filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use the same file name, that's why you only get one output.

You should try :

```
with open('new1.csv', 'r', newline='') as x:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(x, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    index=0
    for x in data_reader:
        # Reset your pdf variable
        pdf=FPDF()
        ...
        filename='Test'+str(index)+'.pdf'
        pdf.output(filename,'F')
        index+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding 1) you're adding all your rows to the same pdf object - make new objects for every row, ie. inside the loop. Regarding 2), some clarification is necessary - what do you mean by "unique"? That each PDF you produce has a different name? That is easy, just replace:

```
for x in data_reader:
```

with:

```
for i, x in enumerate(data_reader):
```

and then, as i contains the row number, create filenames dynamically like this:

```
pdf.output('Test{}.pdf'.format(i), 'F')
```

If, however, you want to ensure that consequent runs of your program won't overwrite previously created output files, this becomes a little bit more complicated.